# CSS hover effect on single results from mysql fetch

Tags: php, mysql, css, hover

I looked up online and didn't find the answer. English is my second language, so I think I'm not looking with the good words. I have a search engine on my website and I want to have a "bump" effect when I hover a result. The problem is, when I hover a result, it affects all of them simultaneously.

HTML-PHP

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $input1 = $row['name'];
    echo '<div class="foo">'; 
    echo '<div class="fooimage">'; 
    echo "<a href='details.php?id=$id'> <img alt='Image goes here' src='portal_user/submit_form/" . $row["Photos"] . "' width=190px height=140px></a>";
    echo '</div>'; 
    echo '<div class="footext">';        
    echo "<div class='input1'>";
    echo "<a href='details.php?id=$id'>$input1</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

CSS

```
.foo {
position: relative;
height: 205px;
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #ececec;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
transition: .7s
}

.foo:hover {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: -5px;
}
```

I want to have the bump effect on the foo div. The results need to stay inline-block to have them in rows and not one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a little jQuery help here I think. I also changed the CSS a little bit, but adjust as necessary:

```js
$( ".foo" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this ).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('hover');
  }
);
```

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 205px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ececec;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
  transition: .7s
}

.foo.hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="fooimage">
    <a href='details.php?id=$id'>
      <img alt='Image goes here' src='http://placehold.it/190x140' width=190px height=140px>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="footext">
    <div class='input1'>
      <a href='#'>$input1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="fooimage">
    <a href='details.php?id=$id'>
      <img alt='Image goes here' src='http://placehold.it/190x140' width=190px height=140px>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="footext">
    <div class='input1'>
      <a href='#'>$input1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="fooimage">
    <a href='details.php?id=$id'>
      <img alt='Image goes here' src='http://placehold.it/190x140' width=190px height=140px>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="footext">
    <div class='input1'>
      <a href='#'>$input1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```